# How to redirect a Jump Link to another page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to redirect a link like this "example.com/abc/#ds" to "example.com"

How to redirect this. I am using WordPress.

Comment: [tour], [mcve] - it's kind of unclear what you're asking. You could either redirect in the `onclick` event of your hyperlink sending you to the `a`nchor or you'd need some sort of JavaScript which checks the current (sub)path in your location and redirecting when a particular string is contained. The latter is a bad approach and even the first one implies an invalid use of anchors - if you want an element to redirect you somewhere else, set the `href` attribute in the anchor element accordingly.

Comment: I need to redirect the anchor link to another url.

Comment: @Faiq Can please specify your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unless you wanted to redirect just `/abc/` as well, you can not do this via a server-side redirect - because your server will never see the `#ds` part (the fragment portion of a URL is not sent to the server.) So you would need to do this via JavaScript on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, but since you are mentioning wordpress and are not showing any code you have tried, I assume you are not comfortable coding, but rather configure via the WP admin interface. I would therefore suggest you use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ for example.